# Why Google put a nofollow tag on their homepage?

Tags: google-search, googlebot, nofollow

[image: Red border say it is nofollow link]

Why did Google put a nofollow tag on their homepage? `Find an ATM near you` is a nofollow link. They own the content on the same domain name. If it is a different domain name then it may make sense as it will pass pagerank, and that it will somehow violate their own terms and conditions. But it is their own domain name, example `https://www.google.co.in/maps/`.

Did they put a nofollow tag only so that the webpage does not crawl from that link? Google may crawl their own homepage often and they probably don't want to waste their CPU resources on that link.

I am just curious to know why they are doing it. Am I missing something?

Comment: They have so many resources dedicated to their crawler that Googlebot doesn't have to worry about a single link hurting Googlebot.   Even a link on their homepage which is the highest Pagerank page on the internet.

Comment: I have read many times that Google calculate pagerank for particular webpage in iterative form, for example if value is not change so much for particular webpage then it will assign that PR number for that webpage. And store the PR value for one month, and later assign that number to order lot's webpages in search, so I thought may be due to avoid more calculation they may assign nofollow tag. I am not sure Googlebot can crawl and calculate PR on same time, do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Actually, PR calculations originally were batch style processes that ran every quarter in a recursive manner until all PR value changes were within a statistically insignificant range. This has changed to a trust network model, since PR is based upon a trust network model, where value and proximity are used to calculate a PR value for new pages in a more real-time manner. It is not as precise, however, there is nothing that stops the old processes from running periodically to yield better results. PR was never thought to be so significant that real-time was important except for new pages.

Comment: What I know so far about PageRank is when they calculate PR for any page without knowing the all links then they calculate PR for any page with recursive formula, For example Page A first time PR is 1.0015 which is calculate based on recursive formula, But when they found other links then PR is changed every time for example first time - 1.001, second time - 1.20, third time - 1.22 and so on... ,So they do iterative calculate till the value is not changed mostly. In old PageRank paper I have read they do max 40 times iterative operation to get approx PR value.

Answer (score 1):

There can be plenty of reasons to put `nofollow` link.

Few years ago Matt Cutt of Google Spam Team has shown lot of examples like wrong title and wrong description on their pages. It can be one of those :)

The generation of this link and it's results depends upon user location, user behavior, users' devices & their configuration, browsers and many more reasons. so they never want to pass link juice from `google.co.in/maps/atms+near+me/` to plenty of them :)

Crawl prioritization can also be the reason.

Links below (language link ) are follow links.

[image: Links below are follow links.]

Comment: 1. Links with nofollow, don't pass the PR value that make sense, but it also don't help to save Pagerank, you might don't know pagerank sculpting concept. 2. Crawl prioritization ? I have asked that question in recent official hangout and they said, links with nofollow does not mean we don't crawl it, we crawl it and hence we see that list of link(including nofollow) on "who links to me" option in search console, it is simply used to don't pass the ranking factor value. I also see others links as well, which doesn't depend on user browser location, for example some old scientist birthday link.

Comment: Crawl prioritization was also the reason behind idea of Nofollow when suggested by google.

Comment: Did you mean google has put this link because google wants its own crawler to crawl google own website?

Answer (score 0):

Google's own domain has to obey their own rules. It sounds odd - but they are even eager to [hire outside experts on SEO](http://searchengineland.com/google-is-hiring-an-seo-to-improve-their-ranking-in-google-225320) in order to improve how well they do this!

Apparently it's more effort to cheat (Create a special case for their own domain) than it is just to follow good practices.

Comment: I'm not sure how putting a `nofollow` on an external link could possibly be an "effort to cheat"

Comment: Google hire other employee for their support.google.com articles or may be for developer.google.com/web articles. My question is only about the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your understanding of nofollow links is not correct. As per the article on **Search Console Help**, the nofollow tag was primarily introduced to tell the importance of a link to the crawler e.g. Sign Up or Login links are kept as nofollow as there's no point inviting the crawler on those pages. Now if we talk about your concern, to which page does the anchor **Find an ATM Near You** links to? I believe a map page, which justifies the statement,

Comment: Google also use nofollow link on some scientist birthday page. It's also use nofollow link for some gallary page. It's not only about the map.

Answer (score 0):

Google use this link on various places depend upon your location. If Google is indexing this links make time and that is own their link also.This no follow link has not much priority also. May be that is the reason.Other wise they makes any  mistake.